# How to check signature of remoted assembly?

Tags: .net, security

I am creating distributed application consists of Web-Server and Windows service running on different machines.
Connection between them is always initiated by Web-Service. 
Web-Server and Windows service assemblies have strong names both.
How could I check that remote application (Windows service) is what I expect? I need to be sure that assembly being running remotely is signed by me.

Protocol between Web-Server and Windows service is a subject to choose too, if it could help to solve problem.

Maybe it could be done using WMI?

Comment: What you're asking for is pretty hard to achieve. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I need to pass critical security data -user's plaintext passwords.
And Kerberos delegation is not the deal - I really need to pass plaintext passwords.

Comment: Explain a little more. Why does the assembly being signed by you allow you to send these passwords?

Comment: Client initiate some script execution (script required plaintext password as argument) on remote machine by doing https-request to Web-Server. Web-Server should pass this password to remote Windows service.

Comment: Do you trust the server the Windows service is hosted on?

Answer (score 0):

You can't be 100% sure of anything a remote party is doing, because **the remote party can always lie**.

Comment: In common sense you are right. But we could trust windows security. 
For example, you could check that specific service is in running state on remote machine using WMI. I can't even imagine how to hack this check.